# Why is the LCP so high?

Tags: performance, pagespeed, pageload, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I'm having trouble with the Largest Contentful Paint (LCP) on [My website](https://www.cointribune.com) when I analyze it with Google PageSpeed Insights. I've cleaned my CSS and asynchronously loaded the CSS that is not on the first screen, but my LCP is still above 4 seconds.

As you can see on [this test](https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cointribune.com%2Fanalyses%2Fjustice%2Fliban-sali-hafez-inflation-braquage-banque-blom-bank%2F), Google is indicating that the LCP element is an HTML paragraph and I don't understand how I can improve my LCP score.

For me, there is no problem in the waterfall because everything seems to be loading normally and the user seems to have the page loaded instantly.
[image: Pagespeed Waterfall screenshot]

Here are some additional details about my setup:

1. My website is a WordPress site
2. I have a custom self-made theme that is designed be performant
3. I'm using WP Rocket for caching and Imagify for converting to WebP and optimizing images
4. I have Cloudflare to help improve performance (with things like the CDN or the files minifies)

If you'd like to test the site, please note that the article is quite old now so it may not be in cache or on the server, potentially skewing the test results. To get an accurate test, please run the test twice.

Can you help me understand why Google PageSpeed Insights is indicating that the LCP element is an HTML paragraph and how I can improve my LCP score?

Thank you in advance for your help